# Combine three results with different columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Output A:

```
+------+-------+--------+
| year | group | amount |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2018 | a     | 5      |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2019 | a     | 6      |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2021 | a     | 1239   |
+------+-------+--------+
```

I have Output B:

```
+------+-------+--------+
| year | group | amount |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2021 | b     | 12     |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2022 | b     | 34     |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2023 | b     | 5691   |
+------+-------+--------+
```

I have Output C:

```
+------+-------+--------+
| year | group | amount |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2018 | total | 12     |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2019 | total | 34     |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2020 | total | 5691   |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2021 | total | 12341  |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2022 | total | 96812  |
+------+-------+--------+
| 2023 | total | 100123 |
+------+-------+--------+
```

I want to combine Output A and Output B and Output C so it looks like this:

```
+------+--------+----------+----------+
| year | total_ | a_amount | b_amount |
|      | amount |          |          |
+------+--------+----------+----------+
| 2018 | 12     | 5        | 0        |
+------+--------+----------+----------+
| 2019 | 34     | 6        | 0        |
+------+--------+----------+----------+
| 2020 | 5691   | 0        | 0        |
+------+--------+----------+----------+
| 2021 | 12341  | 1239     | 12       |
+------+--------+----------+----------+
| 2022 | 96812  | 0        | 34       |
+------+--------+----------+----------+
| 2023 | 100123 | 0        | 5691     |
+------+--------+----------+----------+
```

My goal is to find the % amount on A vs B (this I would just find on my own but that's my "greater goal"). I just need help on how I can transform A B and C to the Desired Output above. I've tried doing a UNION but that doesn't seem to give me what I need.

Is there a way to do this in Snowflake?

Comment: Where is this %amount in your desired output? Those are simply numbers, not percentages.

Comment: Hi Isolated. I would do that on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions here, but unless you are looking for a way to dynamically pivot based on your `GROUP` columns, then this should be a simple `LEFT JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN` situation.  I am assuming in the following code that you have all of years in your C output, but if that isn't the case, then switching to a `FULL OUTER JOIN` with coalesce on your year would work, as well:

First, I'm using CTE to select your sample data:

```
with table_a as (
select *
from (values(2018, 'a', 5),
            (2019, 'a', 6),
            (2021, 'a', 1239))x(year,group_val,amount)
), table_b as (
select *
from (values(2021, 'b', 12),
            (2022, 'b', 34),
            (2023, 'b', 5691))x(year,group_val,amount)
), table_c as (
select *
from (values(2018, 'total', 12),
            (2019, 'total', 34),
            (2020, 'total', 5691),
            (2021, 'total', 12341),
            (2022, 'total', 95812),
            (2023, 'total', 100123))x(year,group_val,amount)
)
```

Then I just `LEFT JOIN` and use `IFNULL` to get ZEROS where you'd have NULL values:

```
select c.year
     , c.amount as total_amount
     , IFNULL(a.amount,0) as a_amount
     , IFNULL(b.amount,0) as b_amount
from table_c c
left join table_a a
  on c.year = a.year
left join table_b b
  on c.year = b.year;
```